# Sklearn, Gaussian Process: XA and XB must have the same number of columns

Tags: python, pandas, numpy, machine-learning, scikit-learn

I am quite new to python and interesting in doing Gaussian regression.
I am under py3.6 and SKlearn 0.19.

I have simple code and I get an error about the dimension of the vectors in cdist called by predict. I understand there's something bad in my input. But I do not see why...

I looked for example of gaussian process regressor, but it does not seems to be the most common tools.

Thank in advance for you help.

Cheers.

Here is a sample of my code:

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
import numpy as np
from sklearn.gaussian_process import GaussianProcessRegressor as gpr
from sklearn.gaussian_process.kernels import RBF, ConstantKernel as C

....

#X_train are the training samples
X_train= np.column_stack((xc,yc,zc))
print('X_train')
print(X_train.shape)
print(X_train)
```

Here is the print of X_train:

```
  X_train  (4576, 3) 
      [[ 0.71958336 -1.12719598  0.47889958]
       [ 0.71958336 -1.12719598  0.47889958] 
      [ 0.71958336 -1.12719598  0.34285071]
       ...   
      [ 0.55255508 -1.18817547 -1.63666023] 
      [ 0.55255508 -1.18817547 -1.70468466]


     [ 0.55255508 -1.18817547 -1.77270909]]
```

here is the target feature on the training:

```
print('v1')
print(v1.shape)
print(v1)
```

its  print

```
v1
(4576,)

0       10.0
1       14.0
2       13.0
3       19.0
....
4573    39.0
4574    16.0
4575    12.0
```

Here is the samples to predict:

```
x = np.column_stack((xp,
                     yp,
                     zp))


print('x')
print(x.shape)
print(x)
```

here is the print:

> ```
> x
> (75, 3)
> [[-1.41421356 -1.41421356 -1.22474487]
>  [-0.70710678 -1.41421356 -1.22474487]
>  [ 0.         -1.41421356 -1.22474487]
>  [ 0.70710678 -1.41421356 -1.22474487]
> .....
>  [ 0.70710678 -0.70710678 -1.22474487]
>  [ 1.41421356 -0.70710678 -1.22474487]
>  [-1.41421356  0.         -1.22474487]
>  [-0.70710678  0.         -1.22474487]
>  [ 0.          0.         -1.22474487]
> ```

Here is the fitting and prediction

```
v1 = v1.ravel()
#default kernel
kernel = C(1.0, (1e-3, 1e3)) * RBF(10, (1e-2, 1e2))

X_train, v1 = make_regression()
model = gpr(kernel=kernel, n_restarts_optimizer=9)
model.fit(X_train,v1)

#Predict v1 
v1_pred = model.predict(x)
```

When runing I get the following error:

> File "test.py", line 189, in test
>       v1_pred = model.predict(x)   File "/usr/local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/sklearn/gaussian_process/gpr.py",
>   line 315, in predict
>       K_trans = self.kernel_(X, self.X_train_)   File "/usr/local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/sklearn/gaussian_process/kernels.py",
>   line 758, in **call**
>       return self.k1(X, Y) * self.k2(X, Y)   File "/usr/local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/sklearn/gaussian_process/kernels.py",
>   line 1215, in **call**
>       metric='sqeuclidean')   File "/usr/local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/scipy/spatial/distance.py",
>   line 2373, in cdist
>       raise ValueError('XA and XB must have the same number of columns ' ValueError: XA and XB must have the same number of columns (i.e.
>   feature dimension.)

Comment: what are `xp`, `yp` and `zp`?

Comment: Sorry, it might be not clear.

To explain my situation I have a chemical analysis of a component in the 3D space.
xc, yc, zc are the variables on my training samples where I know the value of the chemical analysis at the location xc,yc,zc in the 3D space.

xp, yp, zp is the same but in the data I want to predic the unknow chemical analysis.

So in short, these are cartersian coordinates, that should be linked to the chemical analysis

Comment: xp, yp, zp and xc,yc,zx are :
`type <class 'numpy.ndarray'>`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I hav simply copy paste a code and did something stupid:

```
X_train, v1 = make_regression()
```

Just had to remove it.